# Cant redirect output to a file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ubuntu-14.04

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log | sed 's/.* //'
```

Gives me the output on the terminal but when i do

```
 tail -f /var/log/kern.log | sed 's/.* //' >> logfile.txt
```

i cant find anything in the file. From the kernel module i print the names of the executables. For eg if i run `ls` , `kern.log` has `/bin/ls` but with the timestamp etc. So im trying the above to extract only the path and it works as long as i run it without redirecting to an output file, i have also tried `tee logfile.txt` . Still nothing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your sed command is that you're taking "everything that is followed by a space" (the ".* ") and replacing it with "nothing".  What you need to do is to grab everything up to the first space and save it, then replace everything with the saved bit.  To save part of your input string, you put that part of the regex in parentheses: `(.*)`  This can then be put into the replacement string using `\1`.

But there is more to it than that.  sed is greedy -- it will grab as much as it can.  So when you've got a string like "abc def ghi", it will see that "abc def" is followed by a space and grab all of that.  So the question is, how do you get just the first part, up until the first space?

You can select all the characters that are not your delimiter (the space) that are followed by a space.  So in the example above, because the character between **c** and **d** is a space, that won't be selected and only the **abc** part will be.

So what you end up with is this:

```
sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/"`
```

where the matching pattern consists of "anything that's not a space, as many as there are" (which is in parentheses to save it) `"([^ ]\*)"`, a single space `" "`, and then anything else `".*"`.  The replacement string `"\1"` is "whatever matched the part of the regex in the first set of parentheses".

Here's a quick test I did:

```
Testing: cat testout.txt
cat: testout.txt: No such file or directory

Testing: cat testin.txt
abc def ghi
asdf jkl; fdsa ;lkj qwerty 123
Once upon a time
When in the course

Testing: cat testin.txt | sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" >> testout.txt

Testing: cat testout.txt
abc
asdf
Once
When

Testing: cat testin.txt | sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" >> testout.txt

Testing: cat testout.txt
abc
asdf
Once
When
abc
asdf
Once
When

Testing:
```

It starts off with nothing in **testout.txt** and 4 lines in **testin.txt**.  Then it sends the contents of **testin.txt** to sed with the output appending to a file.  Then it shows the contents.  I did it again, then, to show that it's really appending (there are now 8 lines in **testout.txt**, two sets of 4.)  (Note: I added blank lines just to make it easier to read.)

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but isn't only one ">" to put a content in file?

Comment: ">>" is for **appending** content to a file

Comment: Amazing! Sorry :D

Comment: OP already mentioned that redirecting to logfile.txt using `>>` doesnt work. Redirect command `>` will not work either. Whenever it tails it will overwrite the logs. Best is to use append ` >> `